# Custom Ubuntu launcher doesn't launch

Tags: 11.04, launcher

I use Ubuntu 11.04 and Gnome 2.32.1.

I want to create a new launcher for Sql Developer on the desktop with the following value:

```
Name : SqlDeveloper
Command : /bin/sh /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
Icon : A icon in the directory of sql developer
```

When I click or double-click on the launcher nothing happen.

> $ ls -l /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh -rwxr-xr-x /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the file ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk was empty.
Adding `Terminal=true` to the launcher help me to find what was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to add `Terminal=true`

Comment: It wasn't this answer but its help me to find the problem. The problem was that the file ~/.sqldeveloper/jdk was empty. I dont know why but its worked when i launch from a terminal, probably the environement vars. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use full path inside script executed by launcher. That is: in `sqldeveloper.sh` replace `~` with path to `home` dir.