# How do I replace a binary with a shell script in a unity launcher?

Tags: unity, eclipse, .desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Ubuntu launcher doesn't launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101317/custom-ubuntu-launcher-doesnt-launch)

I used [How to pin Eclipse to the Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80013/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-unity-launcher) this to pin Eclipse to unity launcher. But now I need to replace eclipse binary with script in order to use custom gtk config. Here is a sh file(named `ec`):

```
#!/bin/sh
GTK2_RC_FILES=gtkrc-sar ./eclipse
```

And here's desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/mighter/development/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/mighter/development/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

If I replace `eclipse`(binary name) with `ec`(sh name), It won't run. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you make `ec` executable?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh yes, but if I double-click it, I get a dialog asking what to do with it(run, view) every time.

Comment: Just to make sure, your shell script name is `ec`, not `ec.sh`, right?  Also, if you're using Nautilus, on double-click it will ask what to do with a shell script, since it's also considered a text file.  So I don't think that's related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the execute permissions to the shell script and make the `terminal=true`

Comment: I've done that, if I set terminal=true, it only opens a terminal window for a second and then closes it.

Comment: What happens when you try to run that shell script manually on the terminal?

Comment: eclipse is launched.